# Encrpyt with RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa

I need to encrypt some text in C# .NET 4.7.2 and the cipher i need to use is RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding. However the built-in C# class, `RSACryptoServiceProvider` doesn't seem to have MGF1 padding.

How do I encrypt with a public key and RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding?

The code I currently have:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2('path to certificate');
var rsa = cert.PublicKey.Key as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
var dataToEncrypt = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
var encryptedByteArray = rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, true).ToArray();

return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedByteArray);
```

Comment: `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding` is a Java-style cipher transformation string, suggesting that interoperability with Java code that uses this transformation string is a requirement. Is that correct?

Comment: @JamesKPolk Yes. they wrote the decryption in java and I want to use C# to encrypt it. is it possible? I have the public key (certificate) from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RSA rsa = ...;
byte[] encrypted = rsa.Encrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSha1);
```

MGF-1 is the only Mask Generation Function defined by RFC thus far, so it is implied.

Also, try to avoid using RSACryptoServiceProvider directly. If you’re on an old version and have to, then passing `true` to its `fOAEP` parameter is the same as requesting OaepSha1 from the new overload.

Comment: Hi Bartonjs, thanks for replying. i did pass in `true` to the `fOAEP` parameter. but it didn't work. I also tried to use the `RSAEncryptionPadding` but it doesn't seem to be available. there is no overloading method that takes the `RSAEncryptionPadding` value.

Comment: the goal is to encrypt my restful request's parameter before calling the endpoint. the vendor returns the 403 (forbidden) response code which means that they cannot decrypt the value i pass into their endpoint.

Comment: Hi @bartonjs this is the right answer. i couldn't get it to work becuase the vendor didn't whitelist my IP... :(